# $\frac{\binom{i}{N}^2}{\binom{N}{2N}}\left(\frac{i}{N}\right)^2= \frac{\binom{i-1}{N}^2}{\binom{N}{2N}}\left(1-\frac{i-1}{N}\right)^2$

Tags: calculus, binomial-coefficients

I have to show that
$$ \frac{\binom{i}{N}^2}{\binom{2N}{N}}\left(\frac{i}{N}\right)^2= \frac{\binom{i-1}{N}^2}{\binom{2N}{N}}\left(1-\frac{i-1}{N}\right)^2
$$

My calculations:

$\frac{\binom{i}{N}^2}{\binom{2N}{N}}\left(\frac{i}{N}\right)^2 = \frac{\left( \frac{N!}{(N-i)!i!}\right)^2}{\left( \frac{(2N)!}{(2N-N)!N!}\right)} \left( \frac{i}{N}\right)^2 = \frac{(N!)^2}{[(N-i)!]^2(i!)^2} \frac{(N!)^2}{(2N)!} \frac{i^2}{N^2} $

further calculations did not lead to the result..

Comment: This does not make sense, did you mean ${2N \choose N}$, etc?

Comment: yeah sure! I'll change it

Comment: You can start by getting rid of the $\binom{2N}{N}$ since it's on both sides. The squares seem also superfluous since all the quantities inside are positive for $1 \leq i \leq N$.

Comment: Hopefully you can take it from there?

Comment: I tried to go from the left side to the right side.